# SSH client on Cgywin windows not working: "no kex alg"

Tags: windows-7, ssh

I've installed http://x.cygwin.com/ and I am having trouble with ssh log on to my remote machine using ssh client from windows.

I have installed the cgywin/x platform on windows, terminal and all works fine. I tried pinging to the ipaddress of remote machine, works fine.

But on running

```
ssh user@remoteip
```

it throws the following error

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal. no kex alg

So I tried the -t switch, it results in no kex alg

```
ssh -t -t user@remoteip
```

Windows Firewall has been disabled. I am on Windows 7 platform, with cgywin installed And I am not able to connect to remote machine.

```
 ssh -v
OpenSSH_3.8.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7d 17 Mar 2004
```

Tried with putty tool, that works fine. I am able to connect just fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use something more up-to-date. OpenSSH 3.8 is more than a decade old.

Comment: @Jakuje Is it possible to update it in cygwin?

Comment: Magnus, did you find a solution to your issue?

Comment: Yes, current Cygwin certainly supports something more up to date. Just run the installed again.

Comment: Yes, thanks for following up Franck & Jakuje.  I upgraded the openssh version.